# Mongo DB security configuration

Tags: mongodb, security

Suppose I am running a mongodb instance on sever which has public IP address `"120.*.*.*`".And for security purpose I want to allow incoming connection from server with public IP `"40.*.*.*"` and "`12.*.*.*`" only.What are the ways to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

opt 1) mongodb 3.6:

```
use admin
db.createUser(
   {
     user: "restricted",
     pwd: "password",
     roles: [ { role: "readWrite", db: "reporting } ],
     authenticationRestrictions: [ {
        clientSource: ["40.0.0.0","12.0.0.0"],
        serverAddress: ["120.0.0.0"]
     } ]
   }
)
```

opt 2) Via operating system firewall